# How to combine several docker web ui's in one dashboard

Tags: web

I am spinning up a docker compose file with several docker containers. Each docker container has its own web UI.

Is there some clever solution to combine them all in one UI. For instance a UI with tabs, where each tab is the "native UI" of the corresponding docker container?

Example of docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

# Rstudio is the Rstudio docker on an R image with several preinstalled 
packages
  rstudio:
    restart: always
    image: mikkelkrogsholm/rstudio
    container_name: rstudio
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"

# Shiny is the Shiny docker on an R image with several preinstalled 
packages
  shiny:
    restart: always
    image: mikkelkrogsholm/shiny
    container_name: shiny
    ports:
      - "3838:3838"
```

Both of these have web UI's that are served at port 8787 and port 3838.

Several people have proposed and iframe solution. But I was wondering if there is a way to reference the docker specific path for the ports, ie: rstudio:8787 and  shiny:3838 when doing that.

All ideas and solutions are welcome.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a Docker question...? More web development.

Answer (score 0):

I found muximux. It does exactly what I was looking for.